# Hello, I need to build a graphic with axis y in minutes:seconds:fractions of a seconds but I can't

Tags: python, date, graphics, axis, min

I have 7 storms with a time difference between IC (intracloud lightning) GC(lightning cloud ground) and I need to plot this time in a bar graph but I can't plot the minutes (y axis). Can someone help me?
Some storms the difference is given by millisecond and I need to plot on x axis (storms) and y axis (time (minutes)).I'm trying to plot but the minutes are all zero

These are my data:

```
Storms (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
time (00:00:00:131.73, 00:00:00:87.57, 00:03:23, 00:00:00:17.13, 00:08:23, 00:07:51, 00:40:41)
```

My code is like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

x = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
y = [00131.73, 087.57, 323, 1713, 823, 751, 4041]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%M:%S.%f'))
plt.bar(x, y)
ax.set_title('a) Diferença de tempo entre o primeiro relâmpago IN e NS', fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel('Tempo (minutos)', fontsize=14)
ax.set_xlabel('Tempestades', fontsize=14)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Current result:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea what you try to do. And I have no idea what means `IC` and `GC`. And I have no idea what you tried and what went wrong. We can't read in your mind, you have to describe all details in question (not in comments). So better show minimal working code with example data and FULL error message - and plot which you get and which you expect.

Comment: maybe you should convert every time to float value - seconds or milliseconds - and use this value to draw bars.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how this site works very well because I'm new here. Now I edited my post

Comment: `3:22` is NOT `323` but `3*60 + 23` (because minute has 60 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code

- `3:23` is NOT `323` but `3*60 + 23` because minute has 60 seconds
- you have to convert `seconds` to `datetime` - i.e using `datetime.fromtimestamp(seconds)` (but here I found small problem - it automatically sets `1970.01.01 01:00` and you have to remove hour `01` to get correct result - `.replace(hour=0)`)

BTW: you have values much bigger than few seconds so for your data it always display `.0000` for millisecond - and I skip `.%f` in code to make plot more readable.

```
from datetime import datetime, time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

x = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7']
y = [131.73, 87.57, 3*60+23, 17*60+13, 8*60+23, 7*60+51, 40*60+41]

y = [datetime.fromtimestamp(s).replace(hour=0) for s in y]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5))
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%M:%S'))
plt.bar(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you would have all times as string with the same data - always hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds - then you could use `strptime()` (`string parse time`) to convert `string` to `datetime`)

Eventually you could try to use modules like [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) to parse strings

---

**EDIT:**

OR you could use `split()` to convert it to total seconds.

And later you can convert it to `datetime` using the same

```
datetime.fromtimestap(total_seconds).replace(hour=0)
```

```
import datetime

y = ['00:00:00:131.73', '00:00:00:87.57', '00:03:23', '00:00:00:17.13', '00:08:23', '00:07:51', '00:40:41']

for s in y:
    parts = s.split('.')
    
    if len(parts) > 1:
        millisecond = float('.' + parts[-1])
    else:
        millisecond = 0.0
        
    other = parts[0].split(':')
    
    if len(other) > 0:
        seconds = int(other[-1])
    else:
        seconds = 0

    if len(other) > 1:
        minutes = int(other[-2])
    else:
        minutes = 0

    if len(other) > 2:
        hours = int(other[-3])
    else:
        hours = 0

    total_seconds = hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds + millisecond

    dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(total_seconds).replace(hour=0)

    print(f'hours: {hours:3} | minutes: {minutes:3} | seconds: {seconds:3} | millisecond: {millisecond: .02f} | total: {total_seconds: 10.2f} | dt: {dt.strftime("%M:%S.%f")}')
```

Result:

```
hours:   0 | minutes:   0 | seconds: 131 | millisecond:  0.73 | total:     131.73 | dt: 02:11.730000
hours:   0 | minutes:   0 | seconds:  87 | millisecond:  0.57 | total:      87.57 | dt: 01:27.570000
hours:   0 | minutes:   3 | seconds:  23 | millisecond:  0.00 | total:     203.00 | dt: 03:23.000000
hours:   0 | minutes:   0 | seconds:  17 | millisecond:  0.13 | total:      17.13 | dt: 00:17.130000
hours:   0 | minutes:   8 | seconds:  23 | millisecond:  0.00 | total:     503.00 | dt: 08:23.000000
hours:   0 | minutes:   7 | seconds:  51 | millisecond:  0.00 | total:     471.00 | dt: 07:51.000000
hours:   0 | minutes:  40 | seconds:  41 | millisecond:  0.00 | total:    2441.00 | dt: 40:41.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried to plot exactly as your code and it's still giving problem. I am not able to place the graph figure here but it is still plotting only 00:00 on the y axis.

Comment: if you get `00:00` then you have wrong values in `y`. In all situations you have to convert values to `datetime` to get correct values on `yaxis`